# Spreadsheet::WriteExcel - Values are changed to scientific notation despite cell being formatted as Text

Tags: excel, perl

I am using the Perl `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` module to create an .xls spreadsheet (I know about `Excel::Writer::XLSX`, but I need to retain the .xls format for backwards compatibility), and some cells are not being written correctly. There are a few cells which have values of the form `1E##`, which Excel interprets as scientific notation by default. To fix this, I'm using `set_num_format('@')` to force the format of the cell to plain text, but it isn't working. If I look at the cell format in Excel once the workbook is generated, it has been set to Text as I expected, but the values have still been changed to numbers of the form `1E+##`.

Declaration of the formats being used:

```
my $formatRS = $workbook->add_format();
$formatRS->set_align('right');
$formatRS->set_align('top');
$formatRS->set_text_wrap();
$formatRS->set_size(8);
$formatRS->set_num_format('@');

my $formatLS = $workbook->add_format();
$formatLS->set_align('left');
$formatLS->set_align('top');
$formatLS->set_text_wrap();
$formatLS->set_size(8);
$formatLS->set_num_format('@');
```

Writing the data:

```
$worksheet2->write($row, 0, "$Eq->[0]",  $formatRS);
$worksheet2->write($row, 1, "$Eq->[1]",  $formatLS);
$worksheet2->write($row, 2, "$Eq->[2]",  $formatLS);
```

Breaking at the point where the data is written shows that the `@Eq` array still contains the right values, and the worksheet is not modified afterwards. Is there any way to stop the data from being mangled like this?

Edit: Wrote up a quick script to demonstrate the problem. This creates a workbook with three cells. The first value is preserved, but the second and third are converted to numbers despite the cells being formatted as Text.

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("Workbook_Test.xls");

my $format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_num_format('@');

my $worksheet1 = $workbook->add_worksheet('sheet');

$worksheet1->write(0, 0, "1E10B", $format);
$worksheet1->write(0, 1, "1E37", $format);
$worksheet1->write(0, 2, "1E10", $format);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `write` to `write_string` works for me:

```
$worksheet1->write_string(0, 0, "1E10B", $format);
$worksheet1->write_string(0, 1, "1E37", $format);
$worksheet1->write_string(0, 2, "1E10", $format);
```

I see `1E37` inside Excel.

[Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) mentions this for `write`:

> the write() method acts as a general alias for several more specific
> methods

and

> The general rule is that if the data looks like a *something* then a
> *something* is written.

I suspect it sees `1E37` and decides that it looks more like a number than a string, so it uses `write_number` and converts it to a number.

Comment: That works, even if I don't format the cell as text. Thanks!

Comment: A note for anyone else reading this: While this works even if you don't set the format to text, if you then edit the cell value in Excel it will be converted to a number. You may want to format it as text AND use write_string().